# Python format and reparse a date fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a unit test which format and parse a date with several formats and one of them cannot be parsed:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31, 23, 59, 58, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
f = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %Z"
string = datetime.datetime.strftime(date, f)
# => '2015/12/31 23:59:58 UTC+00:00'
datetime.datetime.strptime(string, f)
# => ValueError: unconverted data remains: +00:00
```

According to the doc (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior, %Z is good for format UTC, EST, CST, etc. and %z is for +0000, -0400, +1030.

How can I parse this date format (**UTC+00:00**)?

Comment: Where do you define `f`?

Comment: edited, sorry zondo

Answer (score 0):

Works in python 3.6 but not in Python3.5